Problem when reading on /dev/uioX of my UIO device
I'm having trouble reading from the /dev/uio0 file of my UIO device using the following code in a userspace program:
uio_user.c:
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define UIO_DEVICE "/dev/uio0"  // path to uio_device
#define UIO_EVENT "sys/class/uio/uio0/event"

int main() {
  int fd;
  int info;
  void *mapped_memory;
  size_t map_size = 4096;

  fd = open("/dev/uio0", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) {
    perror("error when opening");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  mapped_memory = mmap(NULL, map_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (mapped_memory == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mapping error");
    close(fd);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  while (1) {
    if (read(fd, &info, sizeof(info)) < 0) {
      perror("reading error");
      munmap(mapped_memory, map_size);
      close(fd);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("read in /dev/uio : %d\n", info);
  }

  munmap(mapped_memory, map_size);
  close(fd);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

For memory mapping, I'm using the following function assigned to the mmap field of the uio_info structure:
int uio_hotplug_mmap(struct uio_info *info, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {
    unsigned long len, pfn;
    int ret;

    len = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    pfn = virt_to_phys((void *)shared_mem_buffer) >> PAGE_SHIFT;

    pr_info("uio_device: pfn: %ld \n", pfn);

    ret = io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, pfn, len, vma->vm_page_prot);
    if (ret < 0) {
        pr_err("uio_device: could not map the address area\n");
        kfree(shared_mem_buffer);
        return -EIO;
    }

    pr_info("uio_device: memory map called success: %d\n", ret);

    return ret;
}

To generate interrupts, I've used a timer that calls the uio_event_notify() function. Despite this, the read() function returns an "Inout/Output Error" (EIO) error. I'm not sure why this error occurs or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I've verified all my functions' implementation, and I defined log to make sure that the uio_hotplug_mmap() will be used as mmap() function on user space.

What is the irq member of your struct uio_info set to? If you are only simulating an interrupt with a timer, you should set the irq member to UIO_IRQ_CUSTOM.

It looks like the memory pointed to by shared_mem_buffer was allocated by kmalloc or something similar, so you should use remap_pfn_range instead of io_remap_pfn_range. Also, calling kfree(shared_mem_buffer); in the mmap handler is a bad idea. The mmap handler could be called again.

I've already tried the function remap_pfn_range, and I got the same issue. And instead of kmalloc, I used kzalloc to allocate memory; beside I also tried with kmalloc. kfree(shared_mem_buffer) is called if an error appends on the execution of the function uio_hotplug_mmap.

Yes, and as I wrote, freeing shared_mem_buffer in that function is a bad idea. shared_mem_buffer will then be pointing to freed memory, so the next time the function is called, all hell will break loose. By the way, leaving the irq member set to 0 will cause read() to fail with EIO.

Ok. I removed the kfree on uio_hotplug_mmap, and I also set irq to UIO_IRQ_CUSTOM. But also return the same error

Still, if you examine the uio_read function in "drivers/uio/uio.c" (Linux kernel source), there is only one place where it returns -EIO, although the code varies slightly for different kernel versions.

Thanks a lot for the guidance. The problem was the irq set to UIO_IRQ_NONE; and I set it to another file, and I ran make on the unmodified file. Then on the correct file, I set irq to UIO_IRQ_CUSTOM, then I was able to run read() to wait an interrupt appends. Thanks again
